# Чим відрізняються значення слів «кермо», «стерно» та «руль»?

Tags: вживання-слів, синоніми

Які слова, корені слів або словосполучення слід вживати для позначення:

- пристрою керування (ручки) автомобіля, літака, корабля (steering wheel),
- пристрою керування (ручки) мотоцикла або ровера (handlebar),
- пристрою зміни напрямку, висоти, глибини через зміну напрямку потоку (rudder)
- систем зміни напрямку взагалі та їх частин (steering control, steering arm, steering linkage etc.),
- у похідних словах — прикметниках, дієсловах та інш. (steering, to steer)?

Comment: Я б сказав, що «стерно» не вживається поза контекстом судноплавства, але СУМ-11 цю мою версію спростовує. Проте, «стерном» кермо автомобіля ніхто в наш час не називає.

Answer (score 1):

Стерно й кермо є синонімами, вживаними як у прямому значенні, так і в переносному.

> КЕРМО, а, сер. Пристрій для керування рухом судна, літака, автомашини
>   тощо; стерно. Ми плили власне попри громаду дуже неприємних кам'яних
>   брил.., то й у мене при кермі була горяча [гаряча] робота (Іван
>   Франко, IV, 1950, 388); Я сів за весла, а вона біля керма (Анатолій
>   Шиян, Переможці, 1950, 114); За кермо тракторів, автомашин та
>   комбайнів сідають юнаки, більшість яких має закінчену середню освіту
>   (Хлібороб України, 11, 1967, 15);  * Образно. У наших руках твого
>   [України] щастя кермо! (Іван Нехода, Хто сіє вітер, 1959, 107).   Біля
>   (коло і т. ін.) керма влади бути (стояти і т. ін.) — мати владу в
>   своїх руках, бути на чолі кого-, чого-небудь; керувати (у 2 знач.). І
>   жінка звільнена — ке «слабша половина!» Біля державного стоїть вона
>   керма (Максим Рильський, I, 1956, 414); Кермо влади — влада,
>   керування, керівництво (у 1 знач.); Ні керма, ні вітрил у кого — хтось
>   не контролює своїх дій, учинків, не керує ними. Розумний, здібний з
>   нього хлопець. От тільки витримки завжди було малувато. А тепер і
>   зовсім розгубив її — наче ні керма в нього, ні вітрил (Юрій Шовкопляс,
>   Людина.., 1962, 339).
>
> Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 4, 1973. — Стор. 142.

Виробничий термінологічний бюлетень 1935 року зафіксував слово "руль" в значенні керма. Але зважаючи на сумнозвісну заангажованість бюлетеня, дехто з дослідників мови прямо називає це росіянизмом.

> Цей різновид синонімів можна вважати надлишковим (баластним), який
>   засмічує науково-технологічну термінологію...
>
> Мартиняк О., Лексичні синоніми на національній основі в українській
>   науково-технічній термінології
>   http://ena.lp.edu.ua/bitstream/ntb/6441/1/07.pdf

З огляду на те, що в професійній лексиці пілотів двозначність і синонімія заборонені задля безпеки керування літаком, а також на радянську традицію перекладу, можна вважати, що в авіаційній та судноплавній термінологіі буде переважати лексема "руль" та похідні від неї слова.
Однак в непрофесіональному вжитку краще використовувати слово стерно, оскільки саме воно зафіксовано в якості перекладу в канонічному словнику Грінченка:

> Стерно, на, с. Руль. Левиц. Пов. 349. Мнж. 179.
>
> Словарь української мови: в 4-х тт. / За ред. Б. Грінченка. — К.,
>   1907—1909. — Т. 4. — С. 203.

Comment: *Однак в непрофесіональному вжитку краще використовувати слово стерно* ви маєте на увазі тільки щодо літаків і кораблів чи взагалі теж?

Comment: Стерно логічно використовувати в повсякденному вжитку, в непрофесійному контексті щодо транспортних засобів, в керуванні яких нема потреби дотримуватися суворих правил спілкування, як у диспетчерів і пілотів літака чи штурманів суден.

Comment: Виходить, що слово кермо виходить з ужитку?

Comment: Ні, не виходить. Я написала, що "Стерно й кермо є синонімами, вживаними як у прямому значенні, так і в переносному." В кінці відповіді дала посилання на словник Грінченка, який перекладає руль як стерно. Етимологія стерна і керма споріднена. Головна тема моєї відповіді - різниця між стерном/кермом і рулем, останнє слово можна вважати зайвим запозиченням з російської.

Comment: Був би вдячний якби ви зробили перелік як у запитанні, можливо не всі пункти і вказали, які слова можна вживати в яких випадках, бо боюсь, що у більшості читачів складеться те саме враження, що й у мене.